# Probabilistic Bounds for Balanced Random Walk

Tags: probability, combinatorics, random-walk

For a balanced random walk with $2n$ steps, i.e. a walk that contains $n$ up-movements and $n$ down-movements, I'm trying to estimate some probabilistic results for the maximal deviation during the walk, i.e. how likely the walk is to stray far from the origin.

This is akin to selecting from a bag of $2n$ balls, $n$ of which are red and $n$ of which are blue, without replacement. All walks must, of course, start and end at $(0,0$ and finish at $(2n,0)$. This is the same setup as the [Ballot Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem) with $p=q$.

I'll define the maximal deviation $M$ by:
$$
M: = \max_{1 \leq i \leq 2n}\left(\left| S_i\right|\right)
$$
where $S_i$ is the partial sum of the values from the first $i$ steps.

I'm initially interested in the expected maximal deviation $\mathbb{E}[M]$ and bounds of the form $\mathbb{P}[M \geq \alpha] \leq C_\alpha$. Now $\frac{S_i}{2n-i}$ is a Martingale, so Doob's maximal equality *should* be helpful for the latter, but I can't quite get there. Any help appreciated.

Comment: It's worth noting that Doob's maximal inequality doesn't apply---at least as far as I can see---since your martingale isn't non-negative.

Comment: Intention would be use Doob on $|S_i| / (2n-i) $, which is a non-negative submartingale since $S_i / (2n-i)$ is a martingale. Apologies if that wasn't clear.

Comment: The problem is the singularity for $S_i/(2n-i)$ when $i=2n$.  [You likely want to define this as 0 at $i=2n$, but that definition does not give a martingale since $E[0|S_{2n-1}]\neq S_{2n-1}$.] You would need to "stop" the process at $i=2n-1$ and define $\tilde{S}_i = S_{2n-1}$ for $i \geq 2n-1$. I give another way to do it in the answer below.

Comment: You're right. I'd neglected to mention that the way I was thinking I was thinking about this problem was in the context of a game my young children were playing that was  to this setup. At $2n-1$ the game would be over as one child has won. Thanks for sharing your result.

Answer (score 2):

You can show that, with high probability, the peak magnitude is around $O(\sqrt{n}\log(n))$. Here is one way to do it (not necessarily the tightest). 
Define $Z(t)$ as the accumulated (integer) location for $t \in \{0, 1, 2, ...\}$, and so $Z(0)=0$ and $Z(k)=0$ for all $k \geq 2n$. You can show: 
$$ E[Z(t+1)|Z(t)] = Z(t)\left(1-\frac{1}{(2n-t)}\right) \quad, \forall t \in \{0,1, ..., 2n-1\}$$
In particular, for all $t \in \{0, 1, 2, ...\}$ we get: 
$$ E[Z(t+1)-Z(t)|Z(t)] \leq \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
 \frac{-1}{2\sqrt{n}}&\mbox{, if  $Z(t)\geq \sqrt{n}$} \\
1  & \mbox{, otherwise} 
\end{array}
\right.$$
Also, $|Z(t+1)-Z(t)|\leq 1$ for all $t$.

---

This satisfies the conditions of Lemma 4 in this paper:

http://ee.usc.edu/stochastic-nets/docs/energy-convergence-ton.pdf

In particular we use parameters: 
$$ z_0=0, \theta = \sqrt{n}, \delta_{max} = 1, \beta = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}} $$

Applying that lemma gives:
$$ E[e^{rZ(t)}] \leq D + (1-D)\rho^t  \quad, \forall t \in \{0, 1, 2, ...\}  \quad (Eq. *)$$
where (apologies for all the constants, I am just pulling directly from the lemma):
\begin{align}
r &=\frac{\beta}{1 + \frac{\beta}{3}} = \frac{3}{1 + 6\sqrt{n}}\\
\rho &= 1 - \frac{r\beta}{2} = 1 - \frac{3/4}{\sqrt{n} + 6n}\\
D &= \frac{(e^r - \rho)e^{r\theta}}{1-\rho} \leq \underbrace{\left(\frac{\sqrt{n}+6n}{3/4}\right)}_{1/(1-\rho)}(e)\underbrace{\left(e^{\frac{3\sqrt{n}}{1+6\sqrt{n}}}\right)}_{\leq e} \leq \frac{7n}{3/4}e^2 = \frac{28ne^2}{3}
\end{align}
which uses $(e^r-\rho) \leq e$ (since $r <1$). Since $\rho < 1$ we get $(1-D)\rho^t \leq 1$, and so from (Eq. *):
$$ E[e^{rZ(t)}] \leq D+1 \leq \frac{28ne^2}{3} + 1 \leq \frac{56ne^2}{3} \quad, \forall t \in \{0, 1, 2, ...\} \quad (Eq. **)$$

---

It follows that for any $m>0$ we get: 
$$ e^{rm} P[Z(t)\geq m] \leq E[e^{rZ(t)}] \leq \frac{56ne^2}{3} \quad, \forall t \in \{0, 1, 2, ...\}$$
Fix $c>2$ and let $m=c(\frac{1+6\sqrt{n}}{3})\log(n)$. Then $rm=\log(n^c)$ and
$$ P[Z(t)\geq m] \leq \frac{56ne^2}{3} e^{-rm} = \frac{56ne^2}{3}e^{-\log(n^c)} = \frac{(56/3)e^2}{n^{c-1}}$$
Hence, by the union bound: 
$$P\left[\left(\sup_{t\geq 0} Z(t)\right)\geq m\right] \leq \sum_{t=0}^{2n-1} P[Z(t)\geq m] \leq \frac{(112/3)e^2}{n^{c-2}} $$
This is just the one-sided bound.  By symmetry of the problem the other side has the same probability and so for any constant $c>2$ we get: 
$$ \boxed{P\left[\sup_{t\geq 0} |Z(t)| \geq c\left(\frac{1+6\sqrt{n}}{3}\right)\log(n)\right] \leq \frac{(224/3)e^2}{n^{c-2}}} $$

---

Define $Z^+ = \sup_{t\geq 0} Z(t)$.  Define $d = 112e^2/3$.  Then from (Eq. **)
$$ E[e^{rZ^+}] \leq \sum_{t=0}^{2n-1} E[e^{rZ(t)}] \leq (2n)(dn/2) = dn^2 $$ 
So by Jensen’s inequality: 
$$ e^{rE[Z^+]} \leq dn^2 \implies E[Z^+] \leq \frac{1}{r}\log(dn^2) = \frac{(1+6\sqrt{n})\log(dn^2)}{3}$$
Define $Z^-=-(\inf_{t \geq 0} Z(t))$.  Then the peak magnitude is $P=\max[Z^+,Z^-]\leq Z^++Z^-$ and so: 
$$\boxed{E[P]\leq  \frac{2(1+6\sqrt{n})\log(dn^2)}{3}}$$

Comment: Intuitively it seems the magnitude of this process is "stochastically less than or equal" to that of a symmetric random walk with iid steps, and the law of the iterated logarithm applied to that suggests the limsup  is roughly $\Theta(\sqrt{n\log\log(n)})$, so the $\sqrt{n}$ (plus a little extra) seems fundamental.